# Find Multiple entries in a database using typeorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, repository, typeorm

Connecting to postgres database and using the Repository from typeorm to retrieve entries.

When using find method it searches through the database and only returns one entry even though there are multiple. Have tried two different versions and both return one entry.

```
let response =  await this.repo.find({
  where: {
    service_name: Equal(service_name)
  },
} )

let response = await this.repo.findBy({
  service_name: Equal(service_name)
})
```

Looking through typeorm docs and this is the only suggestion. Is there any other way?
https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options

Comment: Have you checked what the generated sql is, and ran that directly against your db?

Comment: when running the query in the database it returns 3 rows, when the repo.find method only returns one

Comment: @Kaz Can you provide the sql query generated by typeorm?

Comment: Hi @SoroushAhrari, how can I get this information?

Comment: I found the solution. Instead use a query to the repository.  let response = await this.repo.query('select * from table where service_name = \'' + service_name + '\'')